# Convergence of parametric series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could you give me some hint how to decide about convergence of series
$\sum_{n\ge1}\left(\left(-1\right)^n+\alpha^3\right)\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)$, where $0<\alpha\le1$.

It obvious that this series is alternating one, but I failed to bring it to structure of $\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^na_n$ :
$\sum_{n\ge1}\left(\left(-1\right)^n+\alpha^3\right)\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)=$

$\sum_{n\ge1}\left(\alpha^3+1\right)\left(\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n}\right)+\left(\alpha^3-1\right)\left(\sqrt{2n+2}-\sqrt{2n+1}\right)=$
$\sum_{n\ge1}\alpha^3\left(\sqrt{2n+2}-\sqrt{2n}\right)+\left(2\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n}-\sqrt{2n+2}\right)$

The last series is not exactly telescopic one, so counting partial sums is pretty nasty thing. What I am missing here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}$. Alternating series test shows that $\sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}$ is convergent, and by comparison test, $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\alpha^3}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}$ diverges, hence the original sequence diverge.